# C++ Boost Example: Creating and Managing Threads (Compilation Error)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I am currently using Boost 1.54.0. I am following the code from this [example](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.thread-management).

example_44_01.cpp

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void wait(int seconds)
{
  boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{seconds});
}

void thread()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    wait(1);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  boost::thread t{thread};
  t.join();
  return 0;
}
```

So, it looks like all I need is the -lboost_thread, and -lboost_chrono libraries to link to at compile time. I also added the -lboost_system.

Here are my execution scripts.

```
g++-7 -Wall -std=c++1z -g -c example_44_01.cpp -o example_44_01.o
g++-7 -Wall -std=c++1z -g example_44_01.o -o example_44_01 -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono &>result.txt
```

What's going on here? This is the result.txt file:

```
example_44_01.o: In function `boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::duration<long, boost::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > const&)':
/usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:243: undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::hidden::sleep_for(timespec const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've compiled and linked other programs with the same libraries without error. So is the error in the code? This seems doubtful as the code is straight from the documentation. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Just a question: all these features are available in the standard library with the c++1z flag. Do you need to use boost?

Comment: Perhaps, I am simply going through some of the code on the Boost site for learning purposes. I am struck that it didn't work. :/

Comment: You're probably going to kick yourself for this, but the error might be linking to `-lboost_thread` and not `-lboost_thread-mt`. The `-mt` stands for "multithreaded".

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh `mt` variants have been identical for ages, IIRC

Comment: @JordanJelinek my guess is incompatible compilation flags. What compiler version/flags was used when building the libs? Did you build them yourself?

Comment: I know, but a lot of libraries won't find the proper library if -mt isn't set (like for me on OS X, it doesn't happen on Ubuntu).

Comment: I was able to get it to work by excluding Boost, and using the most recent version of cpp though. It still doesn't give me the Boost way. I'll keep at it.

Comment: I will try the -mt, and come back ASAP. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue once because I was indeliberately using different versions of Boost (I had first installed Boost from commandline, then a few months later on, manually from zip).

Try adding the path to your Boost libraries to the compiler. For instance, if your libraries are stored at `/usr/local/lib`, try:

```
g++-7 -Wall -std=c++1z -g example_44_01.o -o example_44_01 -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono &>result.txt
```

Comment: Wow, worked first try. That's exactly what I did, change versions of Boost as you described. TYVM! I'll be sure to add paths for now on.